# Porting C++ OpenCV program to Ubuntu

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, ubuntu, porting

I have a complete program that uses opencv which I have written in C++ on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I have now been asked to assess the possibility of getting the program running on a Ubuntu server, of which I have no experience.

As such, my questions are:

1 - Does any one have a good tutorial for porting applications from C++ Windows to Ubuntu?
2 - on a scale of 1-10 (1=easy) how difficult would this be?
3 - Ubuntu will be running on a server, does this make a difference to OpenCV?

I have had zero experience with Ubuntu so a step by step guide would be really great if anyone can help!

many thanks for your help,

Kay.

Comment: What's the -1 about? SSteve, StevenV, madth3,Brian Nickel, Ryan Bigg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have written your program in standard C++, you will have no problem compiling. The problem might be for example in linking the libraries you are using. Depending on the complexity of your project, you might have to find an adequate building system, like cmake. It's better if you implement the latter first in Windows. Did you build yourself OpenCV? Do the same for Ubuntu, DO NOT USE the distribution OpenCV packages available with Ubuntu.
2. If you have somebody that knows about Ubuntu assisting you, it will be much smoother.
3. No difference, if you use it like a normal work station. If you access remotely, you might have to solve some visualization issues.

Comment: Hi Antonio, thanks for your response! no I just used the libraries that came with the download, I didn't use cmake. But I will use cmake and try that.